# how to automatically generate a csv file when a user press the search button

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have a class base view which i want to automatically download a csv file but dont seem to know what am doing. here is code

**Model.py**

```
class Pv(models.Model):
accounts =(
    ('Sub CF','Sub CF'),
    ('Special','Special'),
    ('Directors','Directors'),
    ('Operations','Operations'),
    ('LSGDP','LSGDP'),
    ('DWAP','DWAP'),
    ('Capacity(USD)','Capacity(USD)')
    )
acc =(
('Yes','Yes'),
('No', 'No')
)

source =(
        ('GOG','GOG'),
        ('Others', 'Others')
      )
pv =(
    ('General','General'),
    ('Honorarium','Honorarium')
   )
center=(
    ('Cost Center 1','Cost Center 1'),
    ('Cost Center 2','Cost Center 2'),
    ('Cost Center 3','Cost Center 3'),
    ('Cost Center 4','Cost Center 4'),
    ('Cost Center 5','Cost Center 5')
       )
stat =(
    ('Completed','Completed'),
    ('Returned','Returned'),
    ('Cancelled','Cancelled')
)
IA_System_Code = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
IA_code = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
Date_recieved = models.DateField()
Pv_reference = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 120)
Source_of_Funding = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = source)
Cost_center = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = center)
Payee = models.CharField(max_length=500)
Description = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
Account_code = models.CharField(max_length=350)
Gross_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Withholding_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Net_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
Status = models.CharField(max_length = 60, choices = stat )
Remarks =models.CharField(max_length = 500, blank = True)
Acc_Impress = models.CharField(max_length = 350,choices=acc)
Date_returned =models.DateField(null=True,blank = True)
Type_of_accounts= models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = accounts)
Type_of_pv = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = pv)
returned_to_chest = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True,\null=True,\
                               default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE,\
                               related_name='create')
modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True,null=True,\
                                default=None ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,\
                                related_name='modified')
class Meta():
        ordering = ["IA_System_Code"]



def __str__(self):
    return self.Description

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = get_current_user()
    if user and not user.pk:
        user = None
    if not self.pk:
        self.created_by = user
        self.created = datetime.now()
    else:
        self.modified_by = user
        self.modified = datetime.now()
    super(Pv, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**view.py**

```
class ReportView(ListView):
model = Pv # model been used

template_name = 'pv/report.html' 

context_object_name = 'all_search_results' 


def get_queryset(self):
   result = super(ReportView, self).get_queryset()
   query = self.request.GET.get('search') # get the search critirial from the template
   today = datetime.datetime.now()
   if query:
       if query == "Withholding":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Withholding_tax__gt\ 
                                      =0.00,Date_recieved__year=today.year) 
       elif query =="Non-Withholding":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Withholding_tax__lte\
                                     =0.00, Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       elif query =="Accountable-Impress":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Acc_Impress__exact\ 
                                     ='Yes',Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       elif query =="Non-Accountable-Impress":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Acc_Impress__exact\
                                     = 'No',Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       else:
           postresult = Pv.objects.all()
       result = postresult
       response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
       response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
       today = datetime.datetime.now()
       data = result
       pvlist =data.filter(Date_recieved__year=today.year)\
                          .order_by('IA_System_Code')
       writer = csv.writer(response)

       writer.writerow(['IA_System_Code','IA_code',\
                       'Date_recieved','Pv_reference',\
                        'Source_of_Funding','Cost_center','Payee',\    
                        'Description','Account_code',\
                        'Gross_amount','Withholding_tax',\   
                        'Net_amount','Status','Acc_Impress',\
                       'Date_returned','Type_of_accounts','Type_of_pv'])
       for pv in pvlist :
           writer.writerow([pv.IA_System_Code,pv.IA_code,pv.Date_recieved,\

                           pv.Pv_reference,pv.Source_of_Funding,\
                           pv.Cost_center, pv.Payee,pv.Description,\  
                           pv.Account_code,pv.Gross_amount,         
                           pv.Withholding_tax,pv.Net_amount,\
                           pv.Status,pv.Acc_Impress,\   
                           pv.Date_returned,pv.Type_of_accounts,\
                           pv.Type_of_pv])
   else:
       result = None
   return result
```

looks like i dont know what am doing. obviously my code is wrong . can any one here me out .
what i want to achieve is the moment the person finish filtering , the csv file should generate automatically.

**Edited**
here is my new code

**view.py**

```
this is my coded my new code.

class ReportView(ListView):
model = Pv # model been used

template_name = 'pv/report.html' 

context_object_name = 'all_search_results' 


def get_queryset(self):
   result = super(ReportView, self).get_queryset()
   query = self.request.GET.get('search') 
   today = datetime.datetime.now()
   if query:
       if query == "Withholding":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Withholding_tax__gt\ 
                                         =0.00,Date_recieved__year=today.year) 
       elif query =="Non-Withholding":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Withholding_tax__lte =0.00,\ 
                                           Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       elif query =="Accountable-Impress":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Acc_Impress__exact\ 
                                        ='Yes',Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       elif query =="Non-Accountable-Impress":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Acc_Impress__exact =\ 
                                        'No',Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       else:
           postresult = Pv.objects.all()
       result = postresult
   else:
       result = None
   return result

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    writer.writerow(['IA_System_Code','IA_code',\
                    'Date_recieved','Pv_reference',
                    'Source_of_Funding','Cost_center','Payee',\
                    'Description','Account_code',\
                    'Gross_amount','Withholding_tax',\
                    'Net_amount','Status','Acc_Impress',\
                    'Date_returned','Type_of_accounts',\
                    'Type_of_pv','returned_to_chest'])
    pvs = self.get_queryset()
    for pv in pvs:
        writer.writerow([pv.IA_System_Code,pv.IA_code,\
                         pv.Date_recieved,pv.Pv_reference,\
                         pv.Source_of_Funding,pv.Cost_center,\
                         pv.Payee,pv.Description,pv.Account_code,\
                         pv.Gross_amount,pv.Withholding_tax,\
                         pv.Net_amount,pv.Status,pv.Acc_Impress,\
                         pv.Date_returned,pv.Type_of_accounts,\
                         pv.Type_of_pv,pv.returned_to_chest])
    return response
```

the edited version of the code works but it does not even open the template for u to filter, it just run the get function . is there a way the code can allow you to filter before it runs the get function.
i seem to not know what am doing. any help will do thank u

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to return your model queryset (that is `PV.objects.filter()` or something) in `get_queryset` method

And then render the result in get method:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;\ 
    filename="somefilename.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    for item in self.get_queryset():
        writer.writerow([item.IA_System_Code, item.IA_code...])
    return response
```

Haven't tested the code, but I hope it helps

**Edited**

this is my coded my new code.

```
class ReportView(ListView):
model = Pv # model been used

template_name = 'pv/report.html' 

context_object_name = 'all_search_results' 


def get_queryset(self):
   result = super(ReportView, self).get_queryset()
   query = self.request.GET.get('search') 
   today = datetime.datetime.now()
   if query:
       if query == "Withholding":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Withholding_tax__gt\ 
                                         =0.00,Date_recieved__year=today.year) 
       elif query =="Non-Withholding":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Withholding_tax__lte =0.00,\ 
                                           Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       elif query =="Accountable-Impress":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Acc_Impress__exact\ 
                                        ='Yes',Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       elif query =="Non-Accountable-Impress":
           postresult = Pv.objects.filter(Acc_Impress__exact =\ 
                                        'No',Date_recieved__year=today.year)
       else:
           postresult = Pv.objects.all()
       result = postresult
   else:
       result = None
   return result

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    writer.writerow(['IA_System_Code','IA_code',\
                    'Date_recieved','Pv_reference',
                    'Source_of_Funding','Cost_center','Payee',\
                    'Description','Account_code',\
                    'Gross_amount','Withholding_tax',\
                    'Net_amount','Status','Acc_Impress',\
                    'Date_returned','Type_of_accounts',\
                    'Type_of_pv','returned_to_chest'])
    pvs = self.get_queryset()
    for pv in pvs:
        writer.writerow([pv.IA_System_Code,pv.IA_code,\
                         pv.Date_recieved,pv.Pv_reference,\
                         pv.Source_of_Funding,pv.Cost_center,\
                         pv.Payee,pv.Description,pv.Account_code,\
                         pv.Gross_amount,pv.Withholding_tax,\
                         pv.Net_amount,pv.Status,pv.Acc_Impress,\
                         pv.Date_returned,pv.Type_of_accounts,\
                         pv.Type_of_pv,pv.returned_to_chest])
    return response
```

the code works but it does not even open the template for u to filter, it just run the get function . is there a way the code can allow you to filter before it runs the get function.

Comment: i tried the code and i got this error 'NoneType' object is not iterable. it looks like the error is on the **for item in self.get_querset()**

Comment: i tried the code and i got this error **'NoneType' object is not iterable**. it looks like the error is on the **for item in self.get_querset()**

Comment: because you do not *return* your queryset

Comment: return queryset . how ?

Comment: return postresult

Comment: please i have post my new code by editing urs . can u check it for me